# Can a type parameter of a generic class be set dynamically through a Type instance?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I want to do something like the code below.

```
    public IList SomeMethod(Type t)
    { 
        List<t> list = new List<t>;
        return list;
    }
```

This, of course, does not work. Is there some other way I can dynamically set the type parameter of a generic class using a reference to a Type instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
public IList SomeMethod(Type t)
{ 
    Type listType = typeof(List<>);
    listType = listType.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { t});
    return (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
}
```

Comment: No problem, as Joel mentioned this is significantly slower because of the reflection overheads.

Comment: You can also skip the 'new Type[] { ... }' bit - MakeGenericType takes params Type[] which means the compiler will automatically construct an array from a comma-separated list of paramaters

Comment: You can also bring this down to a one-liner: `return (IList)Activator.CreateInstnace((typeof(List<>)).MakeGenericType(t));`

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the [`Type.MakeGenericType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method along with [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).

The resulting code is ugly, slow, and opens you up to run time failures for things that you would normally expect to catch at compile time.  None of these have to be a huge deal, but I've seen the last one especially catch other .Net developers (who expect full type safety) off guard.

Personally, I've never done it this way.  Every time I've been tempted I've taken it as an indication that there's a problem with my design and gone back to the drawing board.  I've not regretted that course.

Comment: This is what I meant by Frankensteinish. Gotta say though, I love that they put in hooks like these.

Answer (score 1):

No additional information here, just for those-that-follow sandbox code (I had to try it all out)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ListFromType
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test1 = FlatList(typeof(DateTime));
            var test2 = TypedList<DateTime>(typeof(DateTime));
        }

        public static IList<T> TypedList<T>(Type type)
        {
            return FlatList(type).Cast<T>().ToList();
        }

        public static IList FlatList(Type type)
        {
            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { type });
            var list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
            return (IList) list;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

can you try doing like following, it is generic type,

```
    public IList SomeMethod<T>(T t)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        list.Add(t);
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: No because the type is not known until runtime. The type depends on what the user currently has selected.

Comment: then why dont you use `ArrayList`. you can add any type of items into it.

Comment: Zain the code above was just a super simple example I came up with. In reality I'm dealing with a custom class called Node<In,Out>. As you can see Node has an "In" type and "Out" type. Nodes can only be connected when the "In" type and "Out" type match. So the user will select a Node to add another Node to. The program will get the selected Node's out type, but then it needs to use that Type to set the "In" type of a new Node<> to connect to it.